# How to do "Batched property change" for both properties and subproperties in Polymer 3.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x

Given this code as example:

```js
class DemoElement extends PolymerElement {
   static get template() {
      return html`
         <p>[[abc]]</p>
         <p>[[def]]</p>
         <p>[[obj.a]] [[obj.b]]</p>
         <button on-click="test">test</button>
    `;
   }
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.abc = 1;
      this.def = 9;
      this.obj = {
         a: 1,
         b: 2,
      }
   }
   test() {
      this.setProperties({ abc: this.abc + 1, def: this.def + 1 });
      this.set('obj.a', this.obj.a + 1);
      this.set('obj.b', this.obj.b + 2)
   }
}
customElements.define('demo-element', DemoElement);
```

According to https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/data-system#batched-property-changes, looks like I can make change to DOM in batch, but when I set breakpoint in the **test** event handler, Polymer observer still fires three times, so how to make it fires one time only?

Edit: At first I thought it has anything to do with dom modification, actually it's not. Every ui framework/library have to change dom elements seperately, but the browser will automatically batch these changes.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
test() {
  this.setProperties({
    abc: this.abc + 1,
    def: this.def + 1,
    obj: {
      ...this.obj,
      a: this.obj.a + 1,
      b: this.obj.b + 2,
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: but when obj is large, does that make performance slow (I'm talking about array too)?

Comment: You'd need to run some perf tests on it. However, this should give you one pass data updating in Polymer 3. On the performance side, if you really do have such a large object, then you might think about your data structures and whether you need all that data in a unified place just to change a couple of properties on it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I actually asked about polymer Observer, but at first I thought it's about dom modification. So "Batched property changes" in Polymer Documatation is about observer triggering, but I misunderstood this to dom modification. So this question should be closed.